# AWS AppSync - Get BatchItem without SortKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have an AppSync which reads/updates/delets the data from the dynamo db.

I am facing a scenario where I have to get the batch items with primary key only. I would pass only the primary key and get the data.

The batch get item works when I pass the primary and sort key both, but returns null if I pass only the primary key.

Is there any way we can get the data based on the primary keys only ???

Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
#set($ids = [])
#foreach($id in ${ctx.prev.result})
    #set($map = {})
    $util.qr($map.put("primaryKey", $util.dynamodb.toString($id.primaryKey)))
    $util.qr($ids.add($map))
#end
```

And then pass this $ids to the batch get item, and this returns no data, as I am passing only the primary key

Answer (score 0):

AppSync has some very heplful information about batch operations on the AWS Developer Docs: [Tutorial DynamoDB Batch Resolvers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html)
Following through that tutorial I was able to perform `BatchGetItem` by only providing the `Primary partition key`.

One very impoartant thing to note about the example mapping templates in the tutorial, is that you must change the table name to match your table's name.

For example a `BatchGetItem` request mapping template would look like this:

```js
#set($ids = [])
#foreach($id in ${ctx.args.ids})
    #set($map = {})
    $util.qr($map.put("id", $util.dynamodb.toString($id)))
    $util.qr($ids.add($map))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
    "tables" : {
        "<YOUR TABLE NAME>": {
            "keys": $util.toJson($ids),
            "consistentRead": true
        }
    }
}
```

**Notice**: Replace `<YOUR TABLE NAME>` with the name of your table.

The response mapping template would look like:

```js
$util.toJson($ctx.result.data.<YOUR TABLE NAME>)
```

**Notice**: Replace `<YOUR TABLE NAME>` with the name of your table.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the table has a sort key.